# Assistance With Simple Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, vagrant

I am attempting to write my first Bash script. I am attempting to create a script to launch my main vagrant VM so that I can launch it from any directory. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -n "$1" ]]; 
    then 
    if [["$1" == "up"]];
        then cd /home/user/DevEnv && vagrant up;
    elif [["$1" == "halt"]];
        then cd /home/user/DevEnv && vagrant halt;
    fi
else 
    echo "Must pass up or halt to script";
fi
```

When I run this I get the following output

```
user@Debian ~ $ dev
Must pass up or halt to script
user@Debian ~ $ dev up
/home/user/bin/dev: line 5: [[up: command not found
/home/user/bin/dev: line 7: [[up: command not found
user@Debian ~ $ dev halt
/home/user/bin/dev: line 5: [[halt: command not found
/home/user/bin/dev: line 7: [[halt: command not found
```

The final else seems to be functioning but the commands after `then` seem to being broken after vagrant. I assume I am doing something simple wrong. I would ultimately like to take the argument as a variable and then pass the variable on to vagrant but that seems more complicated right now.

Comment: put s p a c e s between [[   ]]  and everything else.  They are separate commands.  up"]]  should be "up" ]]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need whitespace to separate `[[` and `]]` from the code between them. For example:

```
elif [[ "$1" == "halt" ]];
    then cd /home/user/DevEnv && vagrant halt;
fi
```

This is a good use for the `case` statement, as well:

```
case "$1" in 
   up)
       cd /home/user/DevEnv && vagrant up
       ;;
   halt)
       cd /home/user/DevEnv && vagrant halt
       ;;
   *)
       echo "Must pass up or halt to script"
       ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 3):

Your trailing `;` aren't useful. I also can't understand why you put the `then`s there, you can put them on the same line as the condition. Furthermore, why did you double your brackets? I'm also told that you need spaces inside the brackets.
Your code would look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -n "$1" ]; then 
    if [ "$1" = "up" ]; then
        cd /home/user/DevEnv && vagrant up
    elif [ "$1" = "halt" ]; then
        cd /home/user/DevEnv && vagrant halt
    fi
else 
    echo "Must pass up or halt to script"
fi
```

That's the way I write my bash scripts, but you can keep the `then`s on separate lines. If you do that, you can remove the semicolons.

I do not use `vagrant`, so I couldn't check your script, but the version I've given you should run properly.

Comment: This is good advice except that `==` working in your shell is due to `bash`/`ksh`/`zsh` being very permissive. The standard only allows `=` with the single bracket notation `[`, so it's generally better to use `[ "${foo}" = "${bar}" ]` (POSIX) *or* `[[ "${foo}" == "${bar}" ]]`, but not some inbetween mix which might work, but shouldn't be relied upon. I still think this screams `case` all over the place, though ;-)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the ==. I come from a C background, it didn't shock me. And +1 for using case.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit in the change so I can +1 your answer now :-)

Comment: Thanks ! I'll keep in mind your counsel with the `=`, my "teacher" told me that == or = were the same. I'll report this back to him.